# How can I set the default log in session?

Tags: 11.04, login, gnome, login-screen

I am using 11.04 with Gnome 3 installed. Before I log in I am prompted to choose in which environment I want to log in. Among the possible selections is gnome, how can I set the default choice?

Answer (score 1):

Well - I'm using 10.04 and xUbuntu, and with german menu translation, which is a bit different, but you should as well have a section `settings` where a lot of settings are.

There you should find a group 'session and starting' or similar. There you should be able to select what the default is.

Maybe you have 'save session on shutdown' and 'login to last session'. Using them in combination might lead to the desired result. If you change the settings, but don't save it at shutdown, the start of last (saved) session will always lead to the same, old session.

Comment: I was aware of that because back in the days I had kde and gnome in parallel and I remember setting it like this but in Gnome 3 there is nowhere to select it.

Comment: Then I'm sorry. Sometimes the difference is small, sometimes it's big.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Classic (or Classic Ubuntu, whichever its called) is the 11.04 equivalent of the original GNOME login.   It will load GNOME without Unity, which should be familiar to the old-style GNOME logins from before Unity.

Comment: I am looking to set default login session Gnome 3 and forget it. Its not an issue what to pick but how to set the default one.

Comment: Iirc, the system *remembers* what you last chose to use.

Comment: nope unfortunately it comes back every time with the single Ubuntu option.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. The question is for how to set a certain shell as default.

Comment: Wait, are we talking CLI?  Or are we talking GUI?  If CLI, there's a `usermod` command... if GUI, i dont think there's a default selector system.  @NN: And if you dont think it answers the question, downvote and dont bother saying anything

Comment: I am reffering to GUI in the login screen how can I select the 4th option ie.

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no way to set the default session.  According to my information and testing, though, it should remember what you selected and use that next login (it did for my system, after checking).  The best you can do is just select the session type you want to use before entering your passcode, I guess.